# It requires an additional port for work

Tags: cloud9-ide

The project requires 2 port.

1. For the interface web (`80` or any other e.g. `8080`)
2. To receive technical information with GPS device port `5055`.

How to open a second port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a hosted Cloud9 workspace, you can listen on ports `8080`, `8081`, and `8082`. Only these three are mapped externally. Port `8080` is mapped externally to to `http://<workspacename>-<username>.c9.io` while `8081` and `8082` need a port specifier e.g. `http://<workspacename>-<username>.c9.io:8081`